# Button appearance clicked version

Tags: ios, uibutton

I want my buttons to look a certain way, and instead of subclassing the button, i wrote this

```
[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[EABaseViewController class], nil]setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gradient_border"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[EABaseViewController class], nil]setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gradient_border_grey"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[EABaseViewController class], nil]setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gradient_border_grey"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
  [[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[EABaseViewController class], nil]setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gradient_border_grey"] forState:UIControlStateSelected|UIControlStateHighlighted];
[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[EABaseViewController class], nil]setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"grey_border_grey"] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

The problem is, that when i click the button, instead of changing to image gradient_border_grey it changes its alpha instead. I cannot find how to fix it?

How do I fix it ?

Comment: Did you accidentally set button  images in StoryBoard?

Comment: no i did not set anything in the story board. I added the button, set its text and that is it

Comment: That's strange, the code works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to set the button type as custom to fix the problem